# Use filter method and find the keys with values between 5 to 8 from the given dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

Use filter method and find the keys with values between 5 to 8 from the given dictionary.

Ex:

```
dict1 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4, 'e':5, 'f':6, 'g':7, 'h':8, 'i':9, 'j':0}

output = filter(function1, dict1)
```

`output` should be `['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']`

How to write a lambda function for function1 to get the desired output?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: `output = filter(lambda k: 5 <= dict1[k] <= 8, dict1)`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski would that not be more useful as an answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@StevenRumbalski has given the right answer i.e.,

```
output = filter(lambda k: 5 <= dict1[k] <= 8, dict1)
```